# Why does my SQL Server sqlcmd repeat statement for every blank new line? How can I prevent this?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am trying to pass a long SQL script to `sqlcmd`, but I am getting duplicated results when there are empty lines in my input file. This also happens interactively from the terminal.

Is this normal and expected? Where is this documented?

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
1> select newid();
2> 
3> go
                                    
------------------------------------
197AFAB2-59D0-47A5-AFAE-42DF745DE436

(1 rows affected)
                                    
------------------------------------
0D7B47B6-6871-4DC4-B19E-777FC81686EB

(1 rows affected)
1>
```

Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 17.5.0002.1 Linux (on Docker)

Comment: Well that's definitely not supposed to happen and I can't reproduce this locally. Try it on another machine; also try `SELECT NEWID()` (this will give unique values if the statement is actually executed multiple times; if it gives the same value you know it's just the output being repeated).

Comment: I can reproduce this on `sqlcmd` on Linux, but not on Powershell.

Comment: Same problem.  This is happening on SQLServer running in Docker Linux.  I updated the question to reflect the newid query which better demonstates this issue.

Comment: I would actually suggest that the `sqlcmd` build ((I and the OP are using) on Linux is broken. Notice that the behaviour is completely different [on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWEuu.png) vs [on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5N6W.png)

Comment: Considering this, then I would suggest raising a bug report on [Microsoft's Azure Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) site. If you link to it, I'll be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Please update your question with your O/S and sqlcmd version.  (This is an interesting "find").

Comment: I've posted a [bug report](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/41121901-line-breaks-cause-errors-unexpected-behaviour-sqlc).

Comment: oops me too!  [another bug report](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/41121925-sqlcmd-on-linux-re-executes-query-for-every-blank)

Comment: @granadaCoder, updated

Comment: Can you list your docker base image?  (Thanks)